# Asymptotics of solution of transcendental equation

Tags: asymptotics, algebraic-equations

It seems the real solution of the following equation $$t=u^2+u\log(u)  $$ has no closed form in view of the output of

```
Reduce[t == u^2 + u*Log[u], u, Reals]
```

The question arises about the asymptotics of that solution as $t$ tends to infinity.

Comment: $u=\sqrt{t}-\log(t)/4+o(1)$.

Comment: @ Fedor Petrov : How is that found?

Comment: it is standard technology of asymptotics of implicit and inverse functions, the same as for Lambert $W$-function. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equation has the form
$$u=\sqrt{t-u\log u}.$$
First obvious approximation is $u_0(t)=\sqrt{t}$, second approximation is
$$u_1(t)=\sqrt{t-u_0(t)\log u_0(t)}=\sqrt t-\frac{\log t}4+O\left(\frac{\log^2t}{\sqrt t}\right).$$ Next one is $u_2(t)=\sqrt{t-u_1(t)\log u_1(t)}.$

Comment: @Alexei Ustinov : Thank you. I didn't think of its rewriting.

Answer (score 6):

Denote $f(u)=u^2+u \log u$. Then $$f(\sqrt{t}-\log t/4)=t-\sqrt{t}\log t/2+\log^2t/16+(\sqrt{t}-\log t/4)\log(\sqrt{t}-\log t/4)=\\t-\sqrt{t}\log t/2+\log^2t/16+\sqrt{t}\log\sqrt{t}+\sqrt{t}\log(1-\log t/4\sqrt{t})=\\t+\log^2t/16+O(\log t)>t.$$
Now assume that $f(s)=t$. By monotonicity we have $s=\sqrt{t}+\log t/4-r$, $r>0$. We have $$\log^2t/16+O(\log t)=f(\sqrt{t}-\log t/4)-f(s)=rf'(\theta)$$ for some $\theta$ between $\sqrt{t}-\log t/4$ and $s$. We see that if $r\geq 1$, then $f(t)-f(s)\geq f(\sqrt{t}-\log t/4)-f(\sqrt{t}-\log t/4-1)=2\sqrt{t}+O(1)$, it is not so. Thus $r\leq 1$ and $f'(\theta)=2\theta+\log\theta+1$ is equivalent to $2\sqrt{t}$. It follows that $$r=(1/16+o(1))\log^2 t/\sqrt{t}.$$

Comment: @ Fedor Petrov : Many thanks from me to you for your based solution.